# Inheritance and specialization

Tags: uml

My question is that:- if in class diagram there is a case and in that there are several child classes of parent class and my doubt is which relationship i have to choose e.g. specialization or inheritance.

Comment: In my opinion in both cases you would use the [generalization arrow](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/generalization.html?context=class-diagrams)

Answer (score 3):

The correct name of relationship is Generalization.

Both specialization and inheritance are names used for the same Generalization relationship as a relationship of the child class to its parent.

You say that child class is a specialization (or specializes) parent class. You also say that child class inherits features (attributes and operations) of its parent class (i.e. it has to have all features of the parent plus eventually some more). But the relationship itself is Generalization.